# How can I test the equality of two NodeLists?

Tags: javascript, object, nodelist

Let's say I have a custom function, that I expect will return a NodeList:

`getNodeList('foo');`

I expect this NodeList to be the same NodeList returned from:

`document.querySelectorAll('.foo');`

How can I check that my expectations are correct?

Doing this does not work:

```
getNodeList('foo') == document.querySelectorAll('.foo')
```

I'm sure there's a good technical reason why this doesn't work, since `document.querySelectorAll('.foo') == document.querySelectorAll('.foo')` also does not work, I take it that this is expected.

How can I test whether two NodeLists contain the same HTML nodes?

Comment: Lot's a good answers and I don't know which to vote for :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far seems ok, but it is inefficient (you'll be recomputing `document.querySelectorAll(...)` and `indexOf` possibly many times).

There is also a bug:  if the `querySelectorAll` returns more elements than the first node list, but they are otherwise equal, your function will return `true`.

You can also simplify the comparisons further:

```
function nodeListsAreEqual( list1, list2 ) {
    if ( list1.length !== list2.length ) {
        return false;
    }
    return Array.from( list1 ).every( ( node, index ) => node === list2[ index ] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - you're right about the bug and thanks for alerting me about the inefficiency - seems like a good answer.

Comment: I ended up going with this approach but @mauroc8's answer seems just as good

Answer (score 6):

Array equality is made by reference, not by contents.

```
let a = [1, 2, 3], b = [1, 2, 3]
let c = a
a == c // => true, since both refer to `a`
a == b // => false
```

If you want to compare two array-like objects you have to compare by index.

```
function eq(A, B) {
  if (A.length !== B.length) return false;
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] !== B[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Of course you could always use some functional programming magic:

```
let arrayEq = (A, B) => A.length === B.length && A.every((e, i) => e === B[i]);
```

But it will only work if A is an array (not a NodeList).

---

Then try

```
eq(getNodeList('foo'), document.querySelectorAll('.foo'))
```

or

```
arrayEq(Array.from(getNodeList('foo')), Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo'))
```

Comment: Simply call `Array.prototype.every` with `A` and the callback, and it'll work on NodeLists as well. No need to create an intermediate array.

Comment: Or, if you want to not do prototype stealing magic, `arrayEq(Array.from(a), Array.from(b))`

Comment: Thanks, I added the latter proposal to the answer

Comment: Thanks, seems like a fine answer. Once I've played around with the various solutions I will mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind installing a third-party library, then grab `deep-equal` from NPM and do:

```
deepEqual(Array.from(getNodeList('foo')), Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo')))
```

This ensures your lists are computed only once and encapsulates all the gory details of list-comparison into a separate function. Your code should simply call an equality function and not mix your application concerns with the low-level walking of list structures. (But you probably knew that already!)

If you don't like the wordiness of `Array.from`, use splats:

```
deepEqual([...getNodeList('foo')], [...document.querySelectorAll('.foo')])
```

If efficiency matters, you'll want to do some profiling.

Comment: I am actually already using "deep-extend", so it may make sense for me to include `deep-equal` too...

Comment: Worth a try; definitely profile and test. `NodeList`s are kinda funky as you know (they are, I believe, "live" like HTMLCollections) and they work nicely in when enumerated but for things like equality `Array.from` is often required. But then there's the whole performance hit on realizing an actual array, so YMMV. :) (At least the code looks nicer with the `deepEqual` call. :) )

Comment: I've just tried this with https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message which probably works the same way, and it doesn't work unfortunately - it doesn't compare the actual DOM nodes, so any 2 NodeLists with the same number of nodes will always return true.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. A `shallowEqual` comparison is likely much better here (as that is what the accepted answer essentially does). If things are not working for you, it is possible that it is because the nodes are mutable and something inside the node is different when you call `querySelectorAll` versus when you created the `NodeList`, but the object identities are the same.... Just a thought. Happy you found an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this method which seems to work, using ES6 features:

```
const isEqual = [...getNodeList('foo')].every((node, index) => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo')).indexOf(node) === index
});
```

Essentially, we test that each item in the first NodeList exists in the second NodeList at the same index. If there are any discrepencies between the NodeLists, this should return false.

Comment: What if the second NodeList is longer?

Comment: @RayToal it seems in this case my condition will not work as expected, as pointed out by jnylen's answer

Answer (score 0):

I've revisited this after requiring the need to compare NodeLists that may not share the same order of nodes, but otherwise the nodes are equal, and came up with this:

```
export default function nodeListsAreEqual(actual, expected) {
    if ((actual.length || Object.keys(actual).length) !== (expected.length || Object.keys(expected).length)) {
        return false;
    }

    return Array.from(actual).every(actualNode => {
        return Array.from(expected).some(expectedNode => actualNode === expectedNode)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler but probably faster @mauroc8 version:

```js
     const nodeEq = (A, B) => {
        A = Array.from(A)
        B = Array.from(B)
        if (A.length !== B.length) return false

        return A.every((a, b) => a.innerHTML === B[b].innerHTML)
      }
```